# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.entity_id' in 'field list',

Tags: magento2.4.0

getting error in Magestore Banner Slider,

> 2 exception(s): Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception):
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'main_table.entity_id' in 'field list', query was: SELECT
> `main_table`.`entity_id` FROM `magestore_bannerslider_slider` AS
> `main_table` Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
> found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.entity_id' in 'field list'
>
> Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column
> not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.entity_id' in 'field list',
> query was: SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id` FROM
> `magestore_bannerslider_slider` AS `main_table`

[image]

Comment: Extension installation issues, the column is not created. You need to reinstall this one.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya can you let me know which column is not created in this error?

Comment: entity_id not created.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue. For fixing that I did the following:

1. create a new module: module.xml, registration.php
2. add di.xml

   ```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> 
   <preference for='Magestore\Bannerslider\Block\Adminhtml\Slider\Grid'
                    type='Fix\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Slider\Grid' />
   </config>
   ```
3. add Grid.php

   ```
    namespace Fix\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Slider;
    class Grid extends \Magestore\Bannerslider\Block\Adminhtml\Slider\Grid
    {
        /**
         * @return $this
         */
        protected function _prepareMassaction()
        {
            parent::_prepareMassaction();
            $this->setMassactionIdField('slider_id');
            return $this;
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case ver. 2.3.5 had only app/code/Magestore/Bannerslider/Block/Adminhtml/Slider/Grid.php which contained entity_id that I replaced with slider_id. Trying directly to reproduce after changing it the error was fixed.

Error appeared in var/log/system.log

Reproducing:
Banner Slider -> Manage Sliders (URL contains ..admin/bannerslideradmin/slider/index/..)

Comment: Thanks for adding your answer, but It's always better to add solution in answer instead of 3rd party link.
Please follow best practice for answer on community.